# Insert data attribute in P tag in ContentEditable change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to insert a data attribute in the `<p data-attribute="blah">...</p>` tag when the user hits Enter (key 13) inside a content editable. I have gotten to the point of being notified when the user hits Enter but I am not sure how I can insert the attribute in the element the browser creates as default behaviour.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Explain "not sure". You don't know how to add an attribute, you don't know how to find the element or what else?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. The trouble I am having is that I don't know how to detect the P tag being added (when I hit Enter) in the contenteditable. If I can get access to that tag then I can add in the attribute.

Comment: It doesn't look to me to be the right approach. You see, the user could pur the cursor back in a paragraph and hit Enter there, creating a `<p>` element next to the existing one with the `data-attribute` copied, while the content of the original would be cut at the cursor point. (This actually happens in Chrome, I haven't tested elsewhere.) Would that be ok with you?

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you mean. What you described above is happening right now with me. For example, If I open up Inspector and manually edit the HTML (insert an attribute) of a P tag then, hitting Enter copies over the P tag, minus the content, along with the data-attribute. In my case the data-attribute needs to be unique since it is an 'ID' of the paragraph.

Comment: I forgot to answer your question. Yes that scenario that you described is ok with me. If the user does hit Enter, a new paragraph should be created even if the cursor was in a middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can probably do is keeping track of the paragraphs. Once the `contenteditable` element has been created, you get a list of the paragraphs.

```
<div id="textArea" contenteditable></div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery, since you used its tag):

```
var textArea = $("#textArea"),
    pars = textArea.find("p");

textArea.on("input", function() {
    var curPars = $("p", this);
    curPars.each(function() {
        if ($.inArray(this, pars) === -1) // this is a new paragraph
            this.setAttribute("data-attribute", someIndex);
    });
    pars = curPars;
});
```

Deleted paragraphs will be discarded - you decide what to do with them.

I used the `input` event because it's the most reliable event to keep track of changes on the content, including cutting and pasting from the clipboard using just the mouse. Too bad it's not available on IE8 and lower, and in IE9 it doesn't fire when *deleting* content (!), and IIRC not even on `contenteditable` elements. Uuuugh.

You may want to add the `propertychange` event too, or you can rely on just `keypress` and `mouseup` events.

Comment: This is perfect. A great start to get me going. Thanks!